# Removing some special characters when reading text file with read.table in R

Tags: r, read.table

I have been saving the output of the Android command top into a text file using Python (Bare with me as this is an R inquiry).

Unfortunately, I was missing a parameter that would just save the output as parseable without any ASCII escape commands (See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409053/how-to-disable-color-in-output-of-top-command). I was able to fix that problem using the suggestion in the link.

Since I discovered the fix recently, I have quite a few older non-processed files with these extra characters (see sample output below).

Notepad Output Sample
[image: Notepad Output]

Notepad++ Output Sample
[image: Notepad++ Output]

Copying part of the output from the actual text file:

[s[999C[999B[6n[u[H[J[?25l[H[J[s[999C[999B[6n[uTasks: 279 total,   5 running, 274 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie

Mem:  1702176K total,  1661708K used,  41439232 free,  11583488 buffers

Swap:   425540K total,   345512K used,  81948672 free,   487176K cached

400%cpu 138%user   3%nice 235%sys   5%idle   0%iow   0%irq  19%sirq   0%host

[7m   PID USER         PR  NI VIRT  RES  SHR S[%CPU] %MEM     TIME+ ARGS           [0m

I have an R program that reads these text files and does some post processing which works fairly well MOST of the time. Other instances these extra characters in a given file require manual cleanup.

Is there a way that I could modify my read.table command to tell R to ignore these wherever they are found ?

My code to read the text file and store the output into a CSV file is below. There is additional post-processing after that, which is really not relevant to the ask:

```
for (file in data_files)
    {
        i = i + 1

        ncol <- max(count.fields(paste(folder,file,sep="/"), sep = ""))
        Top_Data_Frame <- read.table(paste(folder,file,sep="/"), header = FALSE, fill=TRUE, col.names=paste0('V', seq_len(ncol)))
        write.csv(Top_Data_Frame, file = paste(folder,(paste((paste("The_Whole_File", i, sep="")),".csv", sep="")), sep="/"), row.names=FALSE)
```

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: hi Darth Ratus! Can you copy and paste the sample into your question? Thanks

Comment: you could run `str_replace_all(example, "[^[:ascii:]]", "")` on the text I suppose...

Comment: I have added an actual chunk of the actual notepad file.

Comment: These are ANSI control sequences - you can strip them using `fansi::strip_ctl(x, ctl = "csi")`.  Read your files in using `readLines()` first.

Comment: Hello Ritchie, using the command suggested left a few stragglers in the file still, so I just made a minor modification that got rid of them all ```fansi::strip_ctl(x, ctl = "all")``` and that solved the problem. Appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
example <- "[s[999C[999B[6n[u[H[J[?25l[H[J[s[999C[999B[6n[uTasks: 279 total, 5 running, 274 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie

Mem: 1702176K total, 1661708K used, 41439232 free, 11583488 buffers

Swap: 425540K total, 345512K used, 81948672 free, 487176K cached

400%cpu 138%user 3%nice 235%sys 5%idle 0%iow 0%irq 19%sirq 0%host

[7m PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S[%CPU] %MEM TIME+ ARGS [0m"

example <- str_remove_all(data, "(?ms)^(.*(?=Tasks))|([\\[a-zA-Z0-9]+ ])|[^[:ascii:]]")

str_match(example, "(?s)Tasks: (\\d+) total, (\\d+) running, (\\d+) sleeping, (\\d+) stopped, (\\d+) zombie\n\nMem: ([0-9K]+) total, ([0-9K]+) used, ([0-9K]+) free, ([0-9K]+) buffers\n\nSwap: ([0-9K]+) total, ([0-9K]+) used, ([0-9K]+) free, ([0-9K]+) cached\n\n([0-9%]+)cpu ([0-9%]+)user ([0-9%]+)nice ([0-9%]+)sys ([0-9%]+)idle ([0-9%]+)iow ([0-9%]+)irq ([0-9%]+)sirq ([0-9%]+)host\n\n\\[([0-9a-z]+) PID USER PR NI VIRT RES SHR S\\[%CPU\\] %MEM TIME\\+ ARGS \\[([0-9a-z]+)") %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%
  select(-1) %>%
  setNames(c("Tasks_total", "Tasks_running", "Tasks_sleeping", "Tasks_stopped", "Tasks_zombie", "Mem_total", "Mem_used", "Mem_free", "Mem_buffers", "Swap_total", "Swap_used", "Swap_free", "Swap_cached", "cpu", "user", "nice", "sys", "idle", "iow", "irq", "sirq", "host", "PID", "CPU"))
```

Comment: if it doesn't work for the larger dataset, please include more examples :-)

Comment: This is epic, thank you for the tip. Will follow the suggestion and provide updates as they become available.